# Bug in mozilla with box-shadow clipping on 4k monitor

Tags: css, mozilla

I have a 4k monitor and Windows 10 with a scale of 150%.
I add the next css properties to my component in focus-state.
`box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px blue; transition: all 0.3s ease;`
In Mozilla Firefox part of box-shadow clipping and also transition is very slow. In Chrome always work perfectly, also in Mozilla if I change scale my browser page to 150-200% everything work fine. Also on 2k monitor this properties work fine in Mozilla.

If you have the same setup - you can check this through this link.
https://mozilla-box-shadow-bug.netlify.app

I describe more detail this problem with HTML and CSS.
https://codepen.io/serhiishf/pen/dyqBMmL
[How look element from codepen in 4k monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jWAQ.png)

HTML code

```
<div></div>
```

CSS code

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 48px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px blue;
}
```

So my question is, can I fix this problem with some manipulations in CSS?

[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2Sqm.png)

[How it look on 4k monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypVyi.png)

Comment: Perhaps update your question with the actual HTML and CSS you are attempting to use (FWIW that link you posted appears to be invalid/not sufficient)

Comment: You can see this problem only in Mozilla browser with 4k monitor and windows display scale 150% .

Comment: So also I add link to codepen and add screenshots

Comment: And what exactly is your question? If there is a bug with Firefox then open a bug ticket with them?

Comment: Maybe exist some trick for fix or prevent this

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can use the outline property to create a similar effect as box-shadow:

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 48px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem